# Tinker laravel check if connection to database exist

Tags: laravel, tinker

i am trying to use tinker to check if my database connection is exist how can i do it?

i tried

php artisan tinker

```
DB::connection('name of database');
```

thank you

Comment: When you start `php artisan tinker` you are already connected to the database as far as I'm aware. Just make an [eloquent query](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-models)... like `Users::all();` or something.

Comment: Why don't you use `php artisan db`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve it in this way
`DB::connection()->getPdo();` // in case you have one database connection
you can specific database name ==>
`DB::connection('name of database')->getPdo();`